# in_array() does not work

Tags: php, arrays

Why does this return true.

```
$needle = TRUE;
$haystack = array('that', 'this');

print in_array($needle, $haystack); // 1
```

EDIT: I am aware that one can pass `in_array()` the strict parameter to check types. I want to know **why** specifically the behaviour I show is exhibited.

Comment: what do you want to find in array, a boolean variable or boolean string? Base on documentation **If needle is a string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive manner.**

Comment: See the explanation on [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and its third parameter, `$strict`.

Comment: I know I can pass in_array() the strict param, but I wanted an answer to my question (which I have below now).

Comment: This is not a duplicate as far as I can tell. I am not asking how to fix this, I am asking why this is this way. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any non-empty string in PHP is equal to `TRUE` when loose comparison is made (i.e. type is ignored). You may test this by doing:

```
var_dump('this' == TRUE);
var_dump('that' == TRUE);
```

[**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/KdDqs)

But the results are quite different when strict comparison is made (i.e. type is taken into consideration):

```
var_dump('this' === TRUE);
var_dump('that' === TRUE);
```

[**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/Wb10D)

In order to enforce strict comparison in the function [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), you have to set the optional third parameter to `TRUE`:

```
$needle = TRUE;
$haystack = array('that', 'this');

var_dump(in_array($needle, $haystack, TRUE));
```

[**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/Vib5N)

Comment: Nice explanation. I understand that one can pass the strict param to compare types, I just wanted to understand the somewhat non-intuitive behaviour I encountered. FWIW I am passing the bool back in a return to a function I don't control (drupal hookesque invocation) wherein lies the in_array(). See [!in_Array() here](http://drupalcode.org/project/commerce_cardonfile.git/blob/075dc820077794fe8283b0c7159a63020f2ef53b:/commerce_cardonfile.module#l1457)